# Should you have multiple Kafka listeners running in seperate threads in one microservice?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, microservices

Sorry for the broad question.

Trying to understand if I should have multiple listeners running on a single microservice, on multiple threads or have a listener per microservice.

Any resources on this, in regards to articles worth reading?

(Use case for context is the message is taken, transformed and sent to another service via REST, done in Python).

Comment: Consumer instances aren't thread safe, so generally, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Kafka documentation says about [multithreaded](https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#multithreaded)

> The Kafka consumer is NOT thread-safe. All network I/O happens in the thread of the application making the call. It is the responsibility of the user to ensure that multi-threaded access is properly synchronized. Un-synchronized access will result in ConcurrentModificationException.

As confluent blog explains about [kafka-consumer-multi-threaded-messaging](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-consumer-multi-threaded-messaging/)

> When implementing a multi-threaded consumer architecture, it is important to note that the Kafka consumer is not thread safe. Multi-threaded access must be properly synchronized, which can be tricky. This is why the single-threaded model is commonly used.

So generally it is safe and risk less to use single threaded mode. But if you can makes sure synchronisations and concurrency behaviours, then you can use multi threaded mode.